# Wald identity for continuous stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes

[Wald's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation) holds for discrete stochastic processes. Is there a version of such equation for continuous stochastic processes?

Answer (score 1):

[On Wald's Equations in Continuous Time](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3212148?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) (1970) summarizes and extends Wald's equation in discrete time to continuous time.

Comment: Two comments: (1) For the Brownian motion, this is a very classical fact, and can be proved by standard approximation of a stopping time by 'discretized' stopping times (taking finitely many values), using the discrete Wald's identity, and passing to the limit. I am sure numerous textbooks on Brownian motion include this result.

Comment: (2) For general local martingales $M_t$,  $\mathbb{E} M_\tau = 0$ is a consequence of the optional stopping theorem (given appropriate integrability conditions, of course), while $\mathbb{E} M_\tau^2 = \mathbb{E} \mathbb \langle M\rangle_\tau$ is a consequence of $M_t^2 - \langle M\rangle_t$ being a martingale.